# R - how to extact information from 2 columns

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe with more than 2 000 000 records. Here is sample data:

```
year <- c(2002, 2002, 2001, 2001, 2000)
type<- c(“red”, “red”, “blue”, “blue”, “blue”)
mydata <- data.frame(year, type)
```

I need to extract the type per year, which would look something like this:

```
2002:
“red”: 2, “blue”: 0
2001:
“red”: 0, “blue”: 2
2000:
“red”: 0, “blue”: 1
```

I am able to extract it separately using table():

```
table(mydata$year)
table(mydata$type)
```

However I do not come up with a way to do it in one table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `aggregate` like below

```
aggregate(type ~ ., mydata, function(x) table(factor(x, levels = unique(type))))
```

which gives

```
  year type.red type.blue
1 2000        0         1
2 2001        0         2
3 2002        2         0
```

---

Another base R option using `xtabs`

```
xtabs(~ year + type, mydata)
```

gives

```
      type
year   blue red
  2000    1   0
  2001    2   0
  2002    0   2
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another approach

```
> library(dplyr)
> data.frame(table(mydata)) %>% 
    pivot_wider(names_from = type, values_from = Freq)
# A tibble: 3 x 3
  year   blue   red
  <fct> <int> <int>
1 2000      1     0
2 2001      2     0
3 2002      0     2
```

Comment: Where do I indicate "year" column? my dataframe has 32 variables.

Answer (score 0):

We could also use `table`

```
table(mydata)
```